# True live stream (HLS) fail-over?

Tags: jwplayer, live-streaming, wowza, http-live-streaming

```
Encoder 1 --------> Wowza Streaming Server 1 (HLS out) ---------->

                                                                     JWPlayer

Encoder 2 --------> Wowza Streaming Server 2 (HLS out) ---------->
```

I'd like the video player (JWPlayer) above to play the feed from encoder 1.  But if that feed goes down for some reason, I'd like it to seamlessly cut to the other feed.  Is this something I do at the Wowza level or at the player level?  How is something like this accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

You can add [failover servers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW22) directly to your playlist. If the client can't load the playlist from the primary server it will try the next one listed (at the same bandwidth). For example:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=500000, RESOLUTION=1920x1080
http://www.example.com/hi/prog_index.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=500000, RESOLUTION=1920x1080
http://backup.example.com/hi/prog_index.m3u8
```

Comment: That sounds promising but I am not writing the playlists so I don't know how to do that.  Wowza automatically generates the playlists, I'm guessing when it packetizes the incoming encode.  How do we tell Wowza to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at the player level. See "Setting up the live stream player" in this post: https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/building-insights-video-experience/

For reference, I also answered this here: [How do I use javascript to automatically switch to a backup live stream if primary fails in JWPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167560/how-do-i-use-javascript-to-automatically-switch-to-a-backup-live-stream-if-prima)