# How do I use javascript to automatically switch to a backup live stream if primary fails in JWPlayer?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am attempting to write a javascript function that will enable an instance of JW Player to automatically switch from a primary live HLS stream to a backup live HLS stream in the event of an error (ex: primary encoder goes down).

What I have so far:

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
```

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    file: "http://server/primary/playlist.m3u8",
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    title: 'Basic Video Embed',
    description: 'work damn you',
});

jwplayer('myElement').on('error', function(event) {
    var prime = document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML;
    var backup = prime.replace("http://server/primary/playlist.m3u8", "http://server/backup/playlist.m3u8");
    document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = backup;
});
```

In my testing this doesn't work (when the primary stops, the function doesn't execute, the player just spins). I've tried ('error'), ('buffering'), ('idle'), all with the same results.

What would I change in this code to accomplish my goal? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

One of our engineers just wrote a great blog post about this solution, including code samples: https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/building-insights-video-experience/

```
insightsPlayer.on('error', function(event) {
  playStream('error');
});

insightsPlayer.on('complete', function(event) {
  playStream(currentStream);
});
```

If there’s an error, the player switches to the error file. The video is a 10-second still that displays an informational slide. Once that completes, the player tries to play the previously determined currentStream.